# How do I make a select statement for the following question?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

Sorry for asking a simple question but how do you create this Select statement and what is your thought process?
I've listed down the following table that I think is needed for this select statement.

Question: Create a SELECT statement to display a listing of the number of times of the service
requested from each staff. Display staff id, staff’s name, service_no, service’s
description and a total number of times requested.

```
Table: SERVICES
Column Name || Constraints || Default Value || Data Type || Length
SERVICE_NO  || Primary Key ||               || VarChar2  || 10
DESCRIPTION ||             ||               || VarChar2  || 50
CONTRACTOR  ||             ||               || VarChar2  || 20
CCONTACT_NO ||             ||               || VarChar2  || 10

Table: SERVICE_REQUEST
Column Name  || Constraints                          || Default Value || Data Type || Length
SR_ID        || Primary Key                          ||               || Number    || 10
SERVICE_NO   || Foreign Key to the SERVICES table    ||               || VarChar2  || 10
STAFF_ID     || Foreign Key to the STAFF table       ||               || VarChar2  || 10
TEC_ID       || Foreign Key to the TECHNICIANS table ||               || VarChar2  || 10
REQUEST_DATE ||                                      ||               || Date      ||
REQUEST_TIME ||                                      ||               || VarChar2  || 10

Table: STAFF
Column Name || Constraints                       || Default Value || Data Type || Length
STAFF_ID    || Primary key                       ||               || VarChar2  || 10
SNAME       ||                                   ||               || VarChar2  || 30
SIC_NO      || Secondary key                     ||               || VarChar2  || 10
SADDRESS    ||                                   ||               || VarChar2  || 70
SPHONE      ||                                   ||               || VarChar2  || 8
POSITION    ||                                   ||               || VarChar2  || 30
HIRE_DATE   ||                                   ||               || Date      || 
SALARY      ||                                   ||               || Number    || 7,2
SCH_ID      || Foreign Key to the SCHOOL table   ||               || VarChar2  || 10
```

Comment: Why don't you try something and show us where you have the problem ? It will be great for you...

Comment: You'll need to join all three tables and use a `group by` clause to show the totals per staff member / service combination. There are many examples online.

Comment: Inner join the Services and staff to the service_request table on their primary keys,
Group by th eolumns you want in the result, and use count(*) for the number of times!

Comment: ```SQL
select s.staff_id, s.sname, ser.service_no, ser.description, count(ser.service_no)
from staff s
inner join service_request sr
on s.staff_id = sr.staff_id
inner join services ser
on ser.service_no = sr.service_no
group by s.staff_id, s.sname, ser.service_no, ser.description
/
```
So I did this for my query, however I am unsure if this is correct as my lecturer did not give any data and I'm unable to check if I'm correct ;-;

Comment: Your query looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Use the query.

```
select s.staff_id, 
s.sname,    
ser.service_no,
ser.description, 
(select count(service_no) from staff where service_no = ser )
 from service_request sr ,services ser
where  s.staff_id = sr.staff_id 
and ser.service_no = sr.service_no;
```